# Unserialize Class From String PHP Not Working

Tags: php, class, object, serialization

I have a custom class in PHP. If I serialize the class and save it to a text file, I can't unserialize it later in another php file. When I try to call the class functions on the object I get

> Call to a member function [functioname()] on a non-object...

I do include the class in both php files.

PHP File 1:

```
$myobject = new myclass();
$temp = serialize($myobject);
file_put_contents('serializetest.txt', $temp);
```

PHP File 2:

```
$s = file_get_contents('serializetest.txt');
$newobject = unserialize($s);
```

Is there some reason why a serialized class would unserialize properly?

Update

If I create an object and use it's main function I can unserialize the unrelated saved object. The class searches for criminal cases. Even though the two objects are entirely different, once I create and use the new object I can suddenly unserialize saved past objects. i.e. The below works but if I removed the first 3 lines of code it wouldn't.

```
$tempcase = new Expungement();
$tempcase->searchCase('4B02305986','Public',true,false);
echo "Case Number 1: " . $tempcase->caseno;

$s = file_get_contents('serializetest.txt');
echo "Serialized Data: " . $s;
$newcase = unserialize($s);
echo "Case Number 2: " . $newcase->caseno;
```

Comment: Does the class definition exist in file 2?  File 2 would still need to know what `myclass` is.

Comment: I include the class file at the top of both pages. include_once 'myclass.php'

Comment: You tried dumping `$newobject` to see what is contains?

Comment: All it comes up with is this " bool(false)". See my comment below though. If I create an unrelated object and use it's main function (which uses other classes) it works. Maybe it's not importing the other classes into memory until they are used?

Comment: If unserialize returned false, then you need to check the contents of `$s`.

Comment: where's the class for this? or do you think it's irrelevant?

Comment: The class file is quite large and contains other custom classes. The main purpose of the class is to call a phantomjs script and parse all the returned data.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked content of "serializetest.txt" and value of $s? 
Are file 1 and file 2 in the same directory?
Sometimes unserialize doesn't work good if you have "complicated" classes with many crossreferences.

Comment: Yes the contents from serialize.txt are fine. My class does include several other classes but they are all included in the mainclass.php. I noticed it works if I do this in file 2.
`$temp = new myObject();
$temp->runmainfunction();
$s = file_get_contents('serializetest.txt');
$newobject = unserialize($s);`

Does that make any sense? Is it calling in the other classes when I create and use an unrelated object before it?

Comment: could you check content of $s after file_get_content?

Comment: If I echo $s it echo's the right data.

I include several custom classes in my mainclass.php. Do I need to include those other minor custom classes individually in my File 2 or will include 'mainclass.php' automatically include those files for use?

Comment: It is irelevant. You shuuld include them everywhere but before calling unserialize. Even if you don't include them unserialization will be made but type of object is __PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name. Could you check this?